# JHipster fieldset of radio buttons

Tags: angular, radio-button, jhipster, fieldset

In a jhipster project I have an Enumeration field with value "A, B, C, D, E".
With the "standard" approach of Jhipster, a Select/Options will be used:

```js
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="myApp.myEntity.myField" for="field_myField">myField</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="myField" formControlName="myField" id="field_myField">
                        <option value="A">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.A' | translate}}</option>
                        <option value="B">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.B' | translate}}</option>
                        <option value="C">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.C' | translate}}</option>
                        <option value="D">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.D' | translate}}</option>
                        <option value="E">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.E' | translate}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Instead of these, I need to use radio buttons, so I change this to:

```js
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="myApp.myEntity.myField" for="field_myField">myField</label>
                    <fieldset class="form-control" name="myField" formControlName="myField" id="field_myField">
                        <input type="radio" value="A" name="field_myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.A' | translate}}</input>
                        <input type="radio" value="B" name="field_myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.B' | translate}}</input>
                        <input type="radio" value="C" name="field_myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.C' | translate}}</input>
                        <input type="radio" value="D" name="field_myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.D' | translate}}</input>
                        <input type="radio" value="E" name="field_myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.E' | translate}}</input>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

Graphically is ok, but values read from DB are not displayed (no radiobutton is selected) and changing are not passed to backend.
Maybe this is not the correct way to display the radio buttons?
How can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="myApp.myEntity.myField" for="field_myField">myField</label>
    <fieldset class="form-control" name="myField" id="field_myField">
      <input type="radio" value="A" formControlName="myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.A' | translate}}</input>
      <input type="radio" value="B" formControlName="myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.B' | translate}}</input>
      <input type="radio" value="C" formControlName="myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.C' | translate}}</input>
      <input type="radio" value="D" formControlName="myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.D' | translate}}</input>
      <input type="radio" value="E" formControlName="myField">{{'myApp.MyFieldType.E' | translate}}</input>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

See for example https://dev.to/bitovi/angular-forms-several-ways-reactive-nested-across-routes-42g3